# Is there a way on Linux bash to highlight all files modified in last N mins of current path

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I see a lot of similar questions, but answers of those questions don't quite meet my needs. The most common answer is to use command like `find . -mmin -60 -maxdepth 1`. But this command only outputs matched files, the thing I want is to output all files like what `ls -al` does, and highlight (like different color) all files which are modified in last N minutes. I don't know if it is possible to combine `find` and `grep` to achieve this goal, thank you for your help in advance!!

Comment: Why is this tagged _zsh_ if you are searching for a bash solution?

Comment: What do you mean by _highlight_? What do you mean by _N mins **of current path**_?

Comment: You could loop over all files in question, and use the _stat_ command to find the modification timestamp. If you find that this is a file of concern, you can "highlight" it in any way you want.

Comment: @user1934428 bash or zsh is not a problem for me, if any solution just works in zsh, I could switch to zsh, vice versa. Current path is pwd path, I am looking for a solution (function or command combination) to highlight (better by color) recently modified files, say 5 minutes, then I can create an alias e.g. lsm to call it

Comment: This makes your question somewhat clearer now. BTW, simply sorting descending by modification time (`ls -Art --full-time`) is not an option? It is not what you asked for, but maybe good enough for your purpose?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your version of `find` supports the `printf` action and you would like to highlight with, e.g., a leading `***`, the following should work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -60 -printf '*** %p\n' -o -print
```

If you prefer colors, and if your terminal supports it, you can use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Example for green:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -60 -printf '\033[32m%p\033[0m\n' -o -print
```

Explanations:

If the file or directory was modified less than 60 minutes ago it is the `printf` action that will we executed, else it is the `print` action.

By default `find` tests and actions are combined with logical AND. `-o`  is the logical OR. It has lower precedence than AND. Here `find` stops as soon as one of two ORed terms evaluates as true.

Comment: That is great. I have not thought of it. And you could even include ANSI escape sequences to get bold, colours etc.

Comment: @domen Sure, ANSI escape sequences can also be used if they are supported by the target terminal. We could even ring bells or whatever is the most convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works fine. Is it possible to highlight them by color? The leading *** is not that easy to see if the output list is long.

Comment: Easiest way to use color is probably something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -60 -exec sh -c 'tput setaf 3; echo "$1"; tput sgr0' sh {} \; -o -print` (my find doesn't have `printf`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell this works perfet! thank you, I need a little bit time to digest this command :)

Comment: @Defisher _Is it possible to highlight them by color?_ Sure, see my updated answer.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thank you! this is what I want!

Comment: @WilliamPursell Nice, and probably much more portable than the `printf` action. If the `printf` utility is installed or if it is built in the shell (e.g., bash), we could use the same `-exec` approach with the `printf` utility/builtin, and also use the ANSI escape codes: `-exec printf '\033[32m%s\033[0m\n' "{}" \;`.